# String parsing SQL

Tags: sql, string

I have a table containing the attributes id and description of several logs. These are the information present in description attribute:

```
Account Name:   G$
Account Domain: XXX
Logon ID:   0x3E7
Logon Type: 5
Logon ID:   0x3E4
Logon GUID: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
Workstation Name:
```

I am trying to write a query where I can parse through the description attribute and retrieve the account name and workstation name for each id.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Is that "Description Attribute" a single field with all of that in it, carriage returns and all?

Comment: that text is all in a single field? if you need to access individual chunks of that string, you'd be better off parsing the text BEFORE you put it into the table and store the relevant chunks in their own fields. string parsing in sql is hideously painful and very inefficient.

Comment: @JNevill: Yes description is a single attribute with all the details in it.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name: I am using MySQL

Comment: You're going to have a bad time. If it's at all possible, do as @MarcB suggested and fix this data so it's in its own table. Writing a query to query  part of this one field and return some other part of this one field is abusively bad.